# Spring Cloud Stream RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

How can I return the message1 received by the addAnnonceInput, I need to return that message to the client.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/annonces")
public void addAnnonce(@RequestBody AnnonceWrapper annonceWrapper) {
    System.out.println(annonceWrapper.toString());
    final Message<AnnonceWrapper> message = MessageBuilder
                                                    .withPayload(annonceWrapper)
                                                    .setReplyChannel(messageStream.acceptDemandeInput())
                                                    .build();
    messageStream.addAnnonceOutput().send(message);
    messageStream.acceptDemandeInput().subscribe(message1 -> System.out.println(message1.getPayload().toString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an unusual use of Spring Cloud Stream; you would probably be better off using Spring Integration directly, and a [Messaging Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway) to wait for the reply.

Doing it manually this way, you would need to use a `CountDownLatch` or a `Future<?>` to suspend the HTTP thread until the response is received (or some timeout occurs).